# ImportError: cannot import name 'PyvtTbl'

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to import PyvtTbl and DataFrame, this error coming.

```
    ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-452740a411c0> in <module>()
----> 1 from pyvttbl import DataFrame
      2 from base import PyvtTbl, DataFrame

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\lib\site-packages\pyvttbl\__init__.py in <module>()
      8 # This software is funded in part by NIH Grant P20 RR016454.
      9 
---> 10 from base import PyvtTbl, DataFrame
     11 
     12 from misc import *

ImportError: cannot import name 'PyvtTbl'
```

I already installed these packages using pip install.

Comment: did you install with ```sudo``` command? are you sure you are using the same ```python```?

Comment: I'm using windows only. So no sudo.,